# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed after saving key to web config c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am using encryption and decryption function using Aes algorithm. I was earlier hardcoding cryptography key. But later due to security reasons i kept it in web config and started getting padding invalid error in decrypt function. Kindly guide me where i am going wrong

```
  public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionKey"].ToString();
        string EncryptionCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionCode"].ToString();        
        byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(EncryptionCode);
        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
       byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        { //Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });

           Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, key);
           // encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case, what is the encoding of the web.config and the file where you stored the key previously? When you read key from config you are using ASCII encoding. Can it be a problem?

Comment: Your names are quite confusing: The password is described as `EncryptionKey` and the salt as `key`. Regarding your issue: If the ASCII encoding is not the cause, you should post sample data (password, salt, ciphertext and expected plaintext). Also the encryption code would be helpful. By the way, a static salt is insecure.

Comment: <add key="EncryptionKey" value="password" />
    <add key="EncryptionCode" value="0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76" /> .  This is how its in web config. Is there any other way other than ASCII encoding to convert to byte and use it.